# loadPath in Gulp

Tags: gruntjs, bower, gulp

I've got Bourbon and Neat installed via Bower (in the /bower-components folder) and I was wondering if I am able to call them in my .scss files like so, using Gulp.

```
@import 'bourbon';
```

I've just switched over from Grunt and was wondering if Gulp had a similar `loadPath` option. I'd normally use this to reference that Bower directory in my Gruntfile.js, like below:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      style: 'expanded',
      loadPath: '<%= app %>/bower_components/foundation/scss'
    files: {
      '<%= app %>/css/app.css': '<%= app %>/scss/app.scss'
    }
  }
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass), that while is a bit slower than gulp-sass is rich with features, such as loadPath.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an example installing bootstrap, Install `gulp-ruby-sass` but before that make sure you have `ruby` installed first:

```
npm install gulp-ruby-sass --save-dev
```

In `gulpfile.js` define the process:

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass')

gulp.task('processSCSS', function () {
  return sass('./path/to/scss/you/mention/@important/main.scss', {
    style: 'compressed',
    loadPath: [
      './path/to/scss',
      './path/to/bower_component/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets'
    ]
  })
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe('./path/to/dest/stylesheets/')
});
```

In `main.scss` just call stylesheet:

```
@import 'bootstrap'
```